# fire angular datatables page event

Tags: angularjs, pagination, datatables

I need to **load data from the server on page change event of datatables**.I am `using angular-datatables.min.js`. but `can not seem to latch on to the page.dt event of the datables through angular scope`. Please help me on this.

Comment: there is no error.I just can not figure out how to call the event using angular scope.something equivalent to:$('#example').dataTable().on('page', function( e, o) {
        // Do something when you paginate the table
   } );

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got it working- but this is what I just had to do.  Might not be the most elegant but I am able to catch the colum-sizing.dt event:

```
$scope.$on('event:dataTableLoaded', function (event, loadedDT) {
    // loadedDT.DataTable is the DataTable API instance
    // loadedDT.dataTable is the jQuery Object
    loadedDT.DataTable.on('column-sizing.dt', function(e, settings) {
        console.log('WOOOHOOOO');
    });
});
```

I catch the angular-datatables event that gets fired when a data table is loaded and then I bind the data tables events on it there.

Comment: Thanks Ryan Drost! I didn't realize angular-datatables triggers its own event 'event:dataTableLoaded'. UpVoted +1